# Not able to re-click md-checkbox after submitting button

Tags: angularjs

I have few checkboxes:

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="b.user[0]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(user[0]) > -1" ng-click="selection(user[0])" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="'Checkbox 1'" ng-false-value="null">Checkbox 1</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox ng-model="b.user[1]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(user[1]) > -1" ng-click="selection(user[1])" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="'Checkbox 2'" ng-false-value="null">Checkbox 2</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox ng-model="b.user[2]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(user[2]) > -1" ng-click="selection(user[2])" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="'Checkbox 3'" ng-false-value="null">Checkbox 3</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox ng-model="b.user[3]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(user[3]) > -1" ng-click="selection(user[3])" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="'Checkbox 4'" ng-false-value="null">Checkbox 4</md-checkbox>

<button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">SUBMIT</button>
```

I am adding the values of these checkboxes in an array. My directive code is:

```
scope.user = ['Checkbox 1','Checkbox 2','Checkbox 3','Checkbox 4'];
scope.selected = [];
scope.toggleSelection = function (value) {
    var idx = scope.selected.indexOf(value);
    if (idx > -1) {
        scope.selected.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
        scope.selected.push(value);
    }
};    
scope.submit = function() {
    scope.b.user = scope.selected;
};
```

But I am getting duplicate values in array. Example: When I click Checkbox 1 and Checkbox 2 and submit the array contains: ['Checkbox 1','Checkbox 2']. But after that the checked marks suddenly disappear and when I again try to click them, there is only ripple effect but not checked mark. Also the array can have duplicate values when I re-click the same checkbox. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you getting an error in your browser console?

Comment: nope,I am not getting any kind of error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@shreyagupta, please find the modified code of yours. There were few logical errors which is causing the problem.
    Controller Code:

```
$scope.user = ['Checkbox 1','Checkbox 2','Checkbox 3','Checkbox 4'];
$scope.selected = ['Checkbox 1'];
$scope.toggleSelection = function (value) {
    var idx = $scope.selected.indexOf(value);
    if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selected.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
        $scope.selected.push(value);
    }
};    
$scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.b.user = $scope.selected;
    console.log($scope.b.user);
};
```

and HTML Code:

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="b.user[0]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(user[0]) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(user[0])" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="'Checkbox 1'" ng-false-value="null">Checkbox 1</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox ng-model="b.user[1]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(user[1]) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(user[1])" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="'Checkbox 2'" ng-false-value="null">Checkbox 2</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox ng-model="b.user[2]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(user[2]) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(user[2])" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="'Checkbox 3'" ng-false-value="null">Checkbox 3</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox ng-model="b.user[3]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(user[3]) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(user[3])" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="'Checkbox 4'" ng-false-value="null">Checkbox 4</md-checkbox>

<button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">SUBMIT</button>
```